# How to convert multiple request headers to custom object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, http-headers

I need to convert multiple request headers (not a single one) in to custom object in Spring. I tried it out using custom converter

```
public class HeadersMapToCustomObjectConverter implements Converter<Map<String,String>, CustomObject>
{
    @Override
    public CustomObject convert(Map<String, String> source) {
        return new CustomObject(source);
    }
}
```

and Controller method signature:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/content", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> process(
HttpServletRequest request,
@RequestHeader CustomObject customObject)
```

which results in error

```
Unhandled exception: 
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'customObject' for method parameter type CustomObject is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:87)
```

`@RequestHeader` annotation requires `Map<String, String>` parameter type to catch all headers, but it breaks implicit conversion.

Comment: I think that you need to implement it by your own.
Take a look at [RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver.java) 
and [this article](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-argumentresolver/)